# Is there a way to manually trigger onAuthStateChanged in firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried several ways, like:

```
auth.currentUser.reload();
auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
```

but none of them works, the `onAuthStateChanged` listener is not getting called. Its very important for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged` event is triggered by the SDK when the user's auth state change, so when it goes from not being signed in to being signed in - or vice versa.

If you want to detect when their ID token changes, you'll want to listen for `onIdTokenChanged` instead.

There is no way to trigger these event from your own code, although you can of course execute the same code yourself whenever you have another need.